# node.js - How to send multiple images to a page on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to send images to a page on my node.js server along with the html? How do I use express static to send images? (Need an example here)

Server side ->

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/login.html');
});

app.post('/m', function (req, res) {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/m/a.png');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/m/b.png');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/m/c.png')
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/m/d.html');
});
```

Comment: To a page? I would say impossible, because resources are requested one by one by the browser. You could use `data-urls` if you really want to, but this is not recommended

Comment: Definitely not impossible

Comment: So then enlighten me how to transfer multiple resources within one HTTP request (not using data urls) in a way a browser understands and displays the resources. It _is_ impossible, you should read the HTTP specs

Answer (score 4):

In a web server, you don't just send multiple images to a page.  Instead, the browser requests the page HTML, parses it, finds `<img>` tags in the HTML and then requests each of those images separately and your web server responds to each separate image request by sending the requested image.

If you put all your images in a common folder, then you can use `express.static()` to handle all the image requests with one line of code.  For example a line of code like this:

```
app.use("/image", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

Would serve all image requests for URLs like this:

```
/image/a.png
/image/b.png
```

by finding the matching `a.png` and `b.png` in the "public" sub-directory below `__dirname` (which is the directory of the script).  You can read more about `express.static()` [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).  You can obviously play with the path of the URL you want to use and the path where the images are found.  The two just have to work together so that `express.static()` can find the right image in the corresponding place on the server hard drive where you've put it.

There is often some confusion in understanding how the separate path components in `app.use()` and `express.static()` work together.  In the above example, the `"/image"` will be part of the request URL and this `app.use("/image", ...)` tells express that you want to apply this particular middleware to any request path that starts with `/image`.

Then `path.join(__dirname, "public")` is telling `express.static()` to take the rest of the URL path after the `/image` and look for that in the subfolder `public` below the directory `__dirname`.  So, if the browser requests `/image/a.png`, the `app.use()` statement will trigger because `/image` matches that URL and then `express.static()` will try to find the remaining part of the path `a.png` in the directory you told it to look in.

On your server hard disk, this would look like this:

```
 /myproject/
     app.js
     login.html
     /public
         a.png
         b.png
```

I've shown login.html in the same directory as app.js only because that's how you're code seems to be currently written.  I personally don't put any public files in the same directory as my server scripts because I want it to be easy to not make mistakes and accidentally expose my server files to the public.

I would more typically do it like this:

```
 /myproject/
     app.js
     /public
         login.html
         a.png
         b.png

app.use("/image", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "login.html"));
});
```

Or, just let `express.static()` serve the login.html file too.